# div onclick prompts yes or no, if yes, div change to different color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am working on a website that receives the user data whether if he is indeed going to help a patient.

i really dont know how to start this and im been on 1 simple function for weeks.

Example: i clicked square, it prompts me yes or no, the color turns yellow.
clicking on the square, which is yellow, will prompt me another yes or no. turning it back to the original color.

```js
function myFunction() {
   if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
       document.getElementByClass("stileone").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
   } 
   else {
        txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
   }


if (confirm('Are you sure you want to save this thing into the database?') == true) {
    // Save it!
} else {
    // Do nothing!
}
```

```css
.foo {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 25%;
}

.blue {
  background: #13b4ff;
}

.whole {
  float: left;
  width: 900px;
  height: 900px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  
}
.purple {
  background: #ab3fdd;
}

.wine {
  background: #ae163e;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class = "whole">

      <div id = "centerbox1" class="foo blue">A1</div>
      <div id = "centerbox2"class="foo purple">A2</div>
      <div id = "centerbox3"class="foo wine">A3</div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div id = "centerbox4"class="foo blue">B1</div>
      <div id = "centerbox5"class="foo purple">B2</div>
      <div id = "centerbox6"class="foo wine">B3</div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are no events at all. [MDN EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: 1. Call the function. 2. Read the error messages you get when you do.

Comment: You haven't attached the `myFunction` to the `div` elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why doesnt the colour of my boxes change when prompted and confirmed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47776790/why-doesnt-the-colour-of-my-boxes-change-when-prompted-and-confirmed)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure `Javascript` solution for your problem.

```js
function myFunction() {
if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
  if(this.style.backgroundColor == "yellow")
    this.style.backgroundColor = "";
  else
    this.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
} else {
  txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
}

  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to save this thing into the database?') == true) {
    // Save it!
  } else {
    // Do nothing!
  }
}

var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
for (i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
  blocks[i].addEventListener("click", myFunction);
}
```

```css
.foo {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 25%;
}

.blue {
  background: #13b4ff;
}

.whole {
  float: left;
  width: 900px;
  height: 900px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.purple {
  background: #ab3fdd;
}

.wine {
  background: #ae163e;
}
```

```html
<div class="whole">
  <div id="centerbox1" class="foo blue">A1</div>
  <div id="centerbox2" class="foo purple">A2</div>
  <div id="centerbox3" class="foo wine">A3</div><br><br>

  <div id="centerbox4" class="foo blue">B1</div>
  <div id="centerbox5" class="foo purple">B2</div>
  <div id="centerbox6" class="foo wine">B3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! but mind if ask how do  i further modify it to cycle in 4 colours? example, blue change to yellow and to red then back to blue?

Comment: You can do it by adding more conditions. Now if we find yellow we reset background but you can add another color if you want.

Comment: sorry for bothering you again... mind if you help me check the code below? i posted another one in the link below, i dont understand why it doesnt change colour when prompted and confirmed. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47776790/why-doesnt-the-colour-of-my-boxes-change-when-prompted-and-confirmed

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve and you are making many mistakes in your code, for start not using events to call your function. With that said here is something that might help you get started:

Click on your first box and see how it behaves whether you click `Yes` or `Cancel`.

```js
$('#centerbox1').on('click', function() {
  $(this).css('background', '#13b4ff');
  if (confirm('Do you want to do this ?')) { 
      $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
  }
})
```

```css
.foo {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 25%;
}

.blue {
  background: #13b4ff;
}

.whole {
  float: left;
  width: 900px;
  height: 900px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  
}
.purple {
  background: #ab3fdd;
}

.wine {
  background: #ae163e;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class = "whole">

      <div id = "centerbox1" class="foo blue">A1</div>
      <div id = "centerbox2" class="foo purple">A2</div>
      <div id = "centerbox3" class="foo wine">A3</div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div id = "centerbox4" class="foo blue">B1</div>
      <div id = "centerbox5" class="foo purple">B2</div>
      <div id = "centerbox6" class="foo wine">B3</div>

    </div>
```

Comment: thank you so much! i you have cleared a whole lot of stress on my shoulders. sorry for many mistakes, i have just started javascript and i was really, really confused. nevertheless, you have been a great help! @zvezdas1989

Comment: @IvanPhuaYouWen No problem happy to help!