# why doesnt the colour of my boxes change when prompted and confirmed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function myFunction() {
if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
  if(this.style.backgroundColor == "white")
    this.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  else if(this.style.backgroundColor == "yellow")
    this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  else if(this.style.backgroundColor == "red")
    this.style.backgroundColor = "" 
  else
    this.style.backgroundColor = "";
} else {
  txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
}

  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to save this thing into the database?') == true) {
    // Save it!
  } else {
    // Do nothing!
  }
}

var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
for (i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
  blocks[i].addEventListener("click", myFunction);
}
```

```css
.foo {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 25%;
}

.white{
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.whole {
  float: left;
  width: 900px;
  height: 900px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<div class="whole">
  <div id="centerbox1" class="foo white">A1</div>
  <div id="centerbox2" class="foo white">A2</div>
  <div id="centerbox3" class="foo white">A3</div><br><br>

  <div id="centerbox4" class="foo white">B1</div>
  <div id="centerbox5" class="foo white">B2</div>
  <div id="centerbox6" class="foo white">B3</div>
</div>
```

for some reason my prompts and conditions doesnt change my boxes to yellow then to red then to the original color. anyone knows why? i expected it to change colors the users press yes to the prompt.

Example: i clicked square, it prompts me yes or no, the color turns yellow. clicking on the square, which is yellow, will prompt me another yes or no. turning it back to the original color.
this question is a follow up of [div onclick prompts yes or no, if yes, div change to different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769965/div-onclick-prompts-yes-or-no-if-yes-div-change-to-different-color/47770269#47770269)

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking or what the issue is. Clicking a square shows 2 prompts, and no boxes turn yellow. It's a much better idea to describe what you *want* to do, as opposed to saying 'this isn't working'

Comment: You are setting background color by using CSS class. Try using inline styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

**Explanation:**

1. I noticed that JavaScript cannot read `element.style` from the `.white` class, but could do so when I inserted in-line CSS to each element. This is demostrated in the following [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trq36qwr/).
2. You were using the `this` scope in your function, without actually providing what `this` actually is. So, I passed a `this` argument in the `click` event handler, and since `this` cannot be used as a function parameter, changed it to `e`.

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {

    if (e.style.backgroundColor == "white")
      e.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    else if (e.style.backgroundColor == "yellow")
      e.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    else if (e.style.backgroundColor == "red")
      e.style.backgroundColor = "white"
    else
      e.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  } else {
    txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
  }

  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to save this thing into the database?') == true) {
    // Save it!
  } else {
    // Do nothing!
  }
}

var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
for (i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
  blocks[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    myFunction(this);
  });
}
```

```css
.foo {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 25%;
}

.whole {
  float: left;
  width: 900px;
  height: 900px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<div class="whole">
  <div id="centerbox1" class="foo" style="background:white;">A1</div>
  <div id="centerbox2" class="foo" style="background:white;">A2</div>
  <div id="centerbox3" class="foo" style="background:white;">A3</div><br><br>

  <div id="centerbox4" class="foo" style="background:white;">B1</div>
  <div id="centerbox5" class="foo" style="background:white;">B2</div>
  <div id="centerbox6" class="foo" style="background:white;">B3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed!

Comment: Please Accept my answer by clicking on the GREEN TICK beside my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {

    if (e.style.backgroundColor == "white")
      e.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    else if (e.style.backgroundColor == "yellow")
      e.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    else if (e.style.backgroundColor == "red")
      e.style.backgroundColor = ""
    else
      e.style.backgroundColor = "";
  } else {
    txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
  }

  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to save this thing into the database?') == true) {
    // Save it!
  } else {
    // Do nothing!
  }
}

var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
for (i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
  blocks[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    myFunction(this);
  });
}
```

```css
.foo {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 25%;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}

.whole {
  float: left;
  width: 900px;
  height: 900px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.purple {
  background: #ab3fdd;
}

.wine {
  background: #ae163e;
}
```

```html
<div class="whole">
  <div id="centerbox1" class="foo" style="background:white;">A1</div>
  <div id="centerbox2" class="foo" style="background:white;">A2</div>
  <div id="centerbox3" class="foo" style="background:white;">A3</div><br><br>

  <div id="centerbox4" class="foo" style="background:white;">B1</div>
  <div id="centerbox5" class="foo" style="background:white;">B2</div>
  <div id="centerbox6" class="foo" style="background:white;">B3</div>
</div>
```

heres the answer i sought for!

---

```js
     <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script language ="javascript">
function myFunction(e) {
  if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {

    if (e.style.backgroundColor == "white")
      e.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    else if (e.style.backgroundColor == "yellow")
      e.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    else if (e.style.backgroundColor == "red")
      e.style.backgroundColor = ""
    else
      e.style.backgroundColor = "";
  } else {
    txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
  }

  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to save this thing into the database?') == true) {
    // Save it!
  } else {
    // Do nothing!
  }
}

var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
for (i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
  blocks[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    myFunction(this);
  });
}
</script>


<style type="text/css">
.foo {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 25%;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}

.whole {
  float: left;
  width: 900px;
  height: 900px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.purple {
  background: #ab3fdd;
}

.wine {
  background: #ae163e;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="whole">
  <div id="centerbox1" class="foo" style="background:white;">A1</div>
  <div id="centerbox2" class="foo" style="background:white;">A2</div>
  <div id="centerbox3" class="foo" style="background:white;">A3</div><br><br>

  <div id="centerbox4" class="foo" style="background:white;">B1</div>
  <div id="centerbox5" class="foo" style="background:white;">B2</div>
  <div id="centerbox6" class="foo" style="background:white;">B3</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my html code that doesnt work even tho i copied and pasted the code snippet

Comment: Instead of copying my answer and reposting it again, you should ACCEPT my answer.

Comment: my bad, new to stack overflow!

Comment: I just saw that you posted the same problem earlier as well?

Comment: i created the other one to ask for a prompt to change the color, but for this post its to ask why doesnt the color change :/, yea i saw the change, i cant approve it due to my reputation

Comment: hey uh sorry to bother you, but i cant get it to work in html, i only just copied it and added the script and style format which doesnt affect the code much. do i need to add anything else to the html since i took it out of code snippet?

Comment: Can you please send me the code INSIDE your original HTML File?

Comment: hi! i added the html into this post above this comments, it apparently works in code snippet but its doesnt work in html...

Comment: I see what the problem is. You must place your `<script>` ***after*** your HTML,  i.e.,  at the end of `<body>` tag,  so that the script loads AFTER the DOM

Comment: You are Welcome!